# How to load datagrid binding information with a button?

Tags: c#

I want a DataGrid to be filled or loaded when the user click the button "load"

This is my Grid:

```
  <Grid>
     <DataGrid Name="test" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="0,0,286.4,190.6" />
     <Button Content="Load" Command="{Binding cmdReset_Click}" Margin="450,0,165.4,702.6"/>   
  </Grid>
```

and this is my ViewModel

```
 namespace test.ViewModel
 {

    class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public DelegateCommand cmdReset_Click { get; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            cmdReset_Click = new DelegateCommand(Reset_Click);
            Items = GetData();
        }

        public class Log
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string PDO { get; set; }
            public string LOCATION { get; set; }
            public string HOSTAME { get; set; }
            public int SEVERITY { get; set; }
            public DateTime TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
            public string MESSAGE { get; set; }

        }

        public List<Log> Items { get; set; } = new List<Log>();

        private List<Log> GetData()
        {                
                List<Log> logs = new List<Log>();               
                    logs.Add(new Log()
                    {
                        PDO = "TEST",
                        ID = "TEST",
                        //LOCATION = "TEST",
                        HOSTAME = "TEST",
                        SEVERITY = "TEST",
                        TIMESTAMP = "TEST",
                        MESSAGE = "TEST",
                    });
                }
            return logs;
        }
        private void Reset_Click()
        {
            Items = GetData();
        }
    }
}
```

Right now I am getting the list info after running the program. What I need to get this info AFTER the Button is clicked

Comment: I added more code..

Answer (score 0):

```
public DelegateCommand cmdReset_Click { get; }

public ViewModel()
{
    cmdReset_Click = new DelegateCommand(Reset_Click);
    Items = GetData();
}

public class Log
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PDO { get; set; }
    public string LOCATION { get; set; }
    public string HOSTAME { get; set; }
    public int SEVERITY { get; set; }
    public DateTime TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
    public string MESSAGE { get; set; }

}

public List<Log> Items {get; set;} = new List<Logs>();


private GetData()
{
   List<Log> logs = new List<Log>();
        logs.Add(new Log()
            {
                PDO = "test",
                ID = "number",
                HOSTAME = "test",
                SEVERITY = "number",
                TIMESTAMP = "nate",
                MESSAGE ="number",
            });
        }
        return logs;

}

private void Reset_Click()
{
    Items = GetData();
}
```

Comment: I would change the List<> to ObservableCollection<> yet.

Comment: thanks! but it does not work as desired... when I run the project the datagrid has already the list information and when I click on the button, nothing happen.. any idea?

Comment: Because in the Reset Click function you assign the same data as in the constructor (if you directly copied the code). If you add any new objects to the list in this function, you can try to set the binding in xaml. for example.
ItemsSource = "{Binding logs, Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}"

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    private List<Log> GetData()
    {
        List<Log> logs = new List<Log>();
        logs.Add(new Log()
        {
            PDO = "test",
            ID = 100,
            HOSTAME = "test",
            SEVERITY = 5,
            TIMESTAMP = DateTime.Now,
            MESSAGE = "number",
        });
        return logs;
    }
}

public class Log
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PDO { get; set; }
    public string LOCATION { get; set; }
    public string HOSTAME { get; set; }
    public int SEVERITY { get; set; }
    public DateTime TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
    public string MESSAGE { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please have in mind that answers containing only code are not considered as complete

Answer (score 0):

For those with the same questions.. here is the answer...

View:

```
<Grid>
     <DataGrid Name="test" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
     <Button Content="Load" Command="{Binding cmdReset_Click}"/>   
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public DelegateCommand cmdReset_Click { get; }

public LoggingViewModel(){
  cmdReset_Click = new DelegateCommand(Reset_Click);
}

public class Log{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string PDO { get; set; }
   public string LOCATION { get; set; }
   public string HOSTAME { get; set; }
   public int SEVERITY { get; set; }
   public DateTime TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
   public string MESSAGE { get; set; }
}

public List<Log> Items { get; set; } = new List<Log>();

private List<Log> GetData(){                
   List<Log> logs = new List<Log>();               
   logs.Add(new Log(){
     PDO = "TEST",
     ID = "TEST",
     //LOCATION = "TEST",
     HOSTAME = "TEST",
     SEVERITY = "TEST",
     TIMESTAMP = "TEST",
     MESSAGE = "TEST",
    });
  }
    return logs;
}

private void Reset_Click(){
  Items = GetData();
  this.OnPropertyChanged("Items");
}
```